# Howto Prevent IFraming w/ Whitelist

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, whitelist

I'm creating some IFrameable content. We want the user to be able to IFrame this page, but only from a set list of domains.

Is there anything that we can check to see what the domain name of the parent page is?

```
if (top != self) { top.location.replace(self.location.href); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `location` of the parent page is not visible if that page is not in your security context (Same Origin Policy). You can of course look at the `document.referrer` of your own frame, but this isn't totally waterproof... referrer-checking on the client side is marginally less useless than on the server-side, but it can still be circumvented by something like a refresh-forwarder in the frame.

The `frame-ancestors` restriction in [Content Security Policy](http://people.mozilla.org/~bsterne/content-security-policy/details.html) may one day allow this.

Answer (score 2):

As bobince said, `document.referrer` looks to be your best bet. You would check this in the page that would be the src of the iFrame. However, HTTP referer information can be easily spoofed so this method isn't very secure.

This article shows how to do it using PHP: [How to bypass the REFERER security check](http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_62_how-to-bypass-the-referer-se)

Comment: I'm going to bet most people aren't skilled enough to build an iframe into their site and have it pass a valid referer. The goal is to keep the general public from seeing the iframe in someone else's site. Thanks for the info.

Comment: That's what I figured, so in that case, `document.referrer` will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this to check if the page is loaded from whitelist domain. I'm sure there are ways around this, but it seems to work.

```
var currentUrl = document.referrer;
var okayUrl = "http://good-domain.com";
var okayUrl2 = "http://another-good-domain.com";

//check if page is loaded in iframe
if ( window.location !== window.parent.location ) {
    //check if parent is a whitelisted domain
    if (currentUrl == okayUrl || currentUrl == okayUrl2)
    {
     //if it is a good domain, then just log the parent url or something
     console.log(currentUrl);
     } else {
     //if it is a bad domain, then do something about it
     alert ("Woah buddy. Can't touch this!");
     window.location = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling";
   }
}
```